# How to invoke non-static method to get redis key using spel?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-el, spring-data-redis

I was reading spring documentation to create custom keys for redis cache.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

One of the example was

```
@Cacheable(value="books", key="T(someType).hash(#isbn)")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

Now this is valid if i want to generate key using hash method of static class. But how to generate key using method of non static class ?

```
class A{

@Cacheable(value="books", key="(A).hash(#isbn)")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)


String hash(){

return ..some logic;

}
```

I tried this way..it was not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the bean name to reference an instance.

```
@Cacheable(value="books", key="@aBeanName.hash(#isbn)")
```